# How can I make materalize dropdown options the same size as the dropdown button

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I am trying to make the dropdown options the same size as my dropdown button, using materializes dropdown menu.

Like you can see below, the dropdown options are wider than the button itself. Even with `contrainWidth: true`.
Does anyone know how to make them be the same size? Thanks.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/L7hop0fz/103/

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <a class="dropdown-trigger btn-large light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="chartsBtn" data-target='dropdownCharts'><i class="material-icons center">chevron_right</i></a>

  <ul id='dropdownCharts' class='.custom2 dropdown-content light-blue lighten-3 black-text'>
    <li class=""><a href="#!" ><i class="material-icons center">equalizer</i></a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#!" ><i class="material-icons center">show_chart</i></a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons center">multiline_chart</i></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript initialize:

```
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
  alignment: 'right',
  hover: true,
  constrainWidth: true,
  coverTrigger: false,
  closeOnClick: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in styles on `.dropdown-content` ,`min-widtht: 100px`  have seted and this is cause of your problem.
set `min-width: unset` to fix it.

and to fix arrow problem , you can put codes into a container.

```js
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
      alignment: 'right',
      hover: true,
      constrainWidth: true,
      coverTrigger: false,
      closeOnClick: false,
    });
```

```css
#dropdownCharts a{
    color: black;
}

#container:hover #chartsBtn .material-icons {
    transform: rotate(+90deg);
}


#dropdownCharts li{
    width: auto;
}

ul.dropdown-content{
    min-width: unset;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <span id="container">
  <a class="dropdown-trigger btn-large light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="chartsBtn" data-target='dropdownCharts'><i class="material-icons center">chevron_right</i></a>


  <ul id='dropdownCharts' class='.custom2 dropdown-content light-blue lighten-3 black-text'>
    <li class=""><a href="#!" ><i class="material-icons center">equalizer</i></a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#!" ><i class="material-icons center">show_chart</i></a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons center">multiline_chart</i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </span>
```

Comment: Thankyou man, by any chance do you know, how to set the arrow to rotate, while the dropdown list is active?
Right now I just have it rotating on hover.
Cheers.

Comment: @Lucho put codes into a container and set `hover` on container

Comment:  I promise last question bro, but do you know how to make the dropdown menu horizontal instead. I've tried setting display: inline, but not sure on the exact configuration.
Thanks either way.